# How to identify a frame / subframe structure

Tags: html, frame

I have a web application which has a very complex frame / subframe / iframe structure. This is generated and managed dynamically. I am writing some selenium tests for this and I have to verify if an element is present. I can do this with xpath (no problem) but I have to select the frame / subframe where to perform the verification.

How can I identify this frame / subframe structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interact with elements in frame you would first need to switch to the frame.  The following can help you with the steps
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames

An old thread :
[How do I switch to a Frame and click on the pop up using web driver (Selenium - Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725982/how-do-i-switch-to-a-frame-and-click-on-the-pop-up-using-web-driver-selenium/12746070#12746070)